# How to split and get key value pairs separated by a colon from a text file

Tags: python, string, text, key-value

Need to split the following content in the text file by the colon and store it into key-value pairs. But it didn't work if there are multiple occurrences in the same line.

[Textfile.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YePt4.png)

```
        with open(textfile.txt, "r+") as myfile:

            for line in myfile:
                v = "\n".join([x.strip() for x in line.splitlines() if ": " in x])
                name, var = v.partition(": ")[::2]
                myvars[name.strip()] = var
                print (name , var)
```

The output should be
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1LhP.png)

```
|Name John                 |
|DoB 01-01-2000            |
|Gender M                  |
|Country USA               |
|State CA                  |
|Profession Engineer       |
---------------------------
```

But this can't split if there are multiple pairs (with :) in the same line

Comment: Can you share your input and desired output in text and not images so we can reproduce the case?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

It's perhaps not the prettiest solution, but it works. I highly advise the use of regex to solve problems like that.
Each line should be subjected to the following:

1. Find out how many colons are in the line in the first place.

```
    obts = re.findall(r'([a-zA-Z]*)(: )', line)
```

2. If there are multiple colons, then process. Find the words preceding the colons, and then treating those words as start/end markers, extract everything between (so in your example Name and DoB should be treated as start and end, extracting everything in between - in the example, it's John plus all the white spaces).

```
    if len(obts) > 1:
        for o in range(0, len(obts)-1):
            getstr = re.findall(rf'{obts[o][0]}(.*){obts[o+1][0]}', strr)
            print(obts[o][0], getstr[0][1:].strip())
```

3. Edge case (last key-value pair) processed outside of the if and outside of the loop. If there is only one colon in the line, the pair will be caught at this step.

```
getstr = re.findall(rf'{obts[-1][0]}(.*)', strr)
print(obts[-1][0], getstr[0][1:].strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict_stg = {}
with open('input_file.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        parts = line.strip().split(':')
        key = parts[0].strip()
        values = parts[1].split(',')
        values = [value.strip().strip("'") for value in values]
        dict_stg[key] = values
print(dict_stg)
for key, values in dict_stg.items():
    print(f'Key: {key}')
    for value in values:
        print(f'Value: {value}')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).